# spring frame work - object doesn't get created

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using @Controller to create controllers in my spring application, but when I start the Tomcat server it seems that particular newly created Controller object does not exist in the JVM. Is there any way to see if that controller has been instantiated etc...? Why spring framework missing to instan

Why this happens? The server is running in debug mode.

Comment: Show important parts of your XML configuration, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with: have you configured your context correctly so that the controller is found by spring. Spring will not automatically load all your controllers simply because they have the @Controller annotation on it.
You need to either define the controller's one by one like:

```
<bean class="com.mypackage.MyController" />
```

Or better (less work at least):

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage" />
```

greetz,
Stijn

Answer (score 0):

If Spring registers your controller, it will output a log statement like this:

> DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping [main]
>   INFO   - Mapped URL path [/your/url/path]
>   onto handler
>   'com.yourcompany.YourControllerClass'

Try searching your logs for lines like this. If you find them, you are not using the correct URL, otherwise you probably have a deployment problem.